# why my user folder is owned by root after a clean install?

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 23.04 and this happened. Last time I installed Ubuntu, the same thing happened. I don't understand why.

This was my config:

From my SSD

- 105mb fat32 in /boot/efi (also used for windows 10)
- 32gb swap
- 105gb ext4 mounted in /
- 385gb btrfs for /home

From my HDD

- 914gb btrfs in /home/my_username/HDD

could it be because i created a partition in my home/user folder at install?

Comment: The ownership of directories is determined by how you mount them. The ownership on the filesystem is tracked by user-id numbers and the numbers matching the users are usually mapped in /etc/passed. use chown -R user:group /home/user/hdd to change the ownership

Comment: i know how to change ownership. And this was my user folder which was owned by root. i guess this is a bug